# How to open gmail from WebView android?

Tags: java, android, webview, gmail

there I am using sites.google.com for my app as a WebView.Here I am having a **mail us** option on my site, when the user clicks on the Main us button it should redirect him to Gmail app rather than a website.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is `mailto:example@gmail.com` it should automatically open a selection of mail apps. You shouldn't have to do any changes in your app, but in the HTML of the webpage.

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=Hello%20world!" target="_blank">Mailto with subject</a>
```